# Android: Alarm's BoradcastReceiver class takes wrong Integer Extra from Intent object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I am developing an application where there are 3 buttons.Say,button_1 for **5 min**, button_2 for **10 min** , button_3 for **15 min**.

when user clicks on one of the button,i set alarm for that time.I am using `OneShotAlarm.class` as BroadcastReceiver for alarm.I put alarm_time(5,10 or 15 min) in intent to fire alarm like,

```
Intent alarm_intent = new Intent(context, OneShotAlarm.class);
alarm_intent.putExtra(SNOOZE_TIME, 5);
```

and I am trying to retrieve this in `OneShotAlarm.class`,but somehow,it keeps on taking 5 there whatever I put into intent at the time of setting alarm.

Though alarm fires for all options correctly and at correct time,but I don't get the value properly in `OnShotAlarm.class`from intent's Integer extra.

I use same alarm request code for all alarms,but creates new objects everytime for setting up alarm.This is,if it concerns.

Hope,I cleared the question enough.Please help me pointing out what I am missing?

**EDIT :**

I forgot to specify that these three buttons are in a widget and I use a broadvcast receiver to catch their clicks.Sorry for the inconvenience when you tried to put your effort to help me!

Comment: Can you post the code of button selection for set time on alarm?

Comment: Probably the trouble is in using same request codes for your Pending Intents. Just resolved such problem myself a week ago. You need to use different request codes, otherwise Android will reuse your Pending Intents without changing them.

Comment: @Egor: thanks for the response.Actually I used this buttons in a widget and a little change got it to work.Same request code was not a problem! :)

Comment: @user370305: thanks for the response,I was able to solve it.Please read my answer! It was a silly thing. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using these three buttons in widget.I forgot to specify that in my question,I am sorry!

There was no problem in my code,It was correct.But what I used to call the BroadcastReceiver for catching clicks of buttons of widget,was having a little problem.

I used these lines in my onUpdate() of WidgetProvider class,

```
receiver = new Intent(context, ClickCounterWidgetReceiver.class);
receiver.setAction("SET_SNOOZE");
receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);                
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);
```

changing the line to below one solved the issue:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```